# Setting "unsupported" as a dataset inside div

Tags: javascript, html, ios, dataset

I am currently using [this script](https://github.com/tmnlsthrn/lotus/blob/master/assets/iosver.js) to determine a user's iOS version, check whether the tweak/app/program is compatible and change the HTML accordingly.
The HTML I am using is:

```
<block>
<div data-min-ios="8.0" data-max-ios="8.3" class="prerequisite">
    <p>Supports iOS 8.0 to 8.3</p>
</div>
</block>
```

I need to be able to use the UNSUPPORTED value from the script, but the line is stumping me:

```
    if ("unsupported" in prerequisite.dataset) {
        message = VERSION_CHECK_UNSUPPORTED.replace("%s", minString).replace("%s", maxString);
    }
```

How do I set "unsupported" as a dataset in the div, so that this will be used instead of UNCONFIRMED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `unsupported` tag to the div using:

```
<div data-unsupported data-min-ios="8.0" data-max-ios="8.3" class="prerequisite">
```